# Map parameter value to it's parameter name in oracle preparedStatement

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement

How can I map parameter value to its parameter name in oracle preparedStatement when calling storedProcedures in java?

The problem is I don't know the parameter's orders, I just know their names.

Comment: Use hibernate, which has HQL that allows named parameters

Comment: i assume you are trying to apply generic maps of param values to various SQL which contains ? params. there is no magic way. you are going to need to map the param names to the ? order somehow. maybe store a list of param names along side the SQL which you can then resolve before the statement call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. (Unless you implement some kind of advanced SQL parser). there is no magic way. you are going to need to map the param names to the ? order somehow. maybe store a list of param names along side the SQL which you can then resolve before the statement call.